# Unable to install modules: module 'login_security' is incompatible with this version of Drupal core

Tags: installation, 9

I'm trying to install the *Login Security* module. When I run `drush en login_security`, I get the following error.

> In ModuleInstaller.php line 91:
>
> Unable to install modules: module 'login_security' is incompatible with this version of Drupal core.

What is the equivalent of the *Login Security* module for Drupal 9?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to install a `1.x` version of [Login Security](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security).

According to the module page, it supports Drupal 9 from version 2.0.

So check your `composer.json` and make sure you are trying to install the 2.0 version.